# Send e-mail when a field has a specific value

Tags: 8, rules, workflows, workbench

I use the Workbench moderation module for Articles workflow. I would like to send an e-mail when Workbench moderation field has the *needs review* value.

I tried using the Rules module, but I don't know how to select this field and compare data. How do I get the value of the Workbench moderation field in a rule?

Comment: Rules is not ready for production use yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when you need to compare the field data,But you can probably do a form alter or modify the Workbench moderation module function.

Then create a component instead of rules and use a parameter if needed for field id or data.In action add send email.

Then you can invoke that component in the function you are using like this:-

rules_invoke_component('rules_save_review_field', 'paramval1', 'paramval2', ....);